# Como eu posso obter valores mais precisos dividindo dois long?

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Estou programando um CNC por conta própria, e eu estou no meio do meu código, e agora eu tenho duas variáveis do tipo `long` que, quando dividido resulta em um valor fracionário exato, mas o Arduino retornando um valor fracionário de apenas 2 casas.

```
long x = 99;
long y = 9;
long z = 9999;
long m = 9999;

(double)x/(double)m; //resulta em 0.01
(double)y/(double)m; //resulta em 0.00
(double)z/(double)m; //resulta em 1.00
```

Como posso obter valores mais precisos dividindo dois valores `long`?

obs.: O resultado máximo da divisão será 1.00

Comment: Olá Gabriel, para uma resposta mais precisa e dentro do contexto do arduino, por gentileza me informe qual Arduino está usando?
Arduino Mega (ou outro da família) ou Arduino DUE (ou outro similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> (double)x/(double)m; //resulta em 0.01
> (double)y/(double)m; //resulta em 0.00
> (double)z/(double)m; //resulta em 1.00
> ```

```
99/9999 = 0.00990099(0099...)  
9/9999 = 0.00090009(0009...)
```

Possivelmente o teu problema esta no `printf()`, não no cálculo:

```
printf(" com 2 dígitos de precisão: %.2f\n", 9.0/9999);
printf("                   default: %f\n", 9.0/9999); // 6 dígitos
printf("com 15 dígitos de precisão: %.15f\n", 9.0/9999);
```

que dá o resultado:

```
% ./a.out
 com 2 dígitos de precisão: 0.00
                   default: 0.000900
com 15 dígitos de precisão: 0.000900090009001
```

Comment: Acho que os `double`s do Arduino nao tem capacidade para 15 digitos, apenas para 6 ou 7.

Comment: Ah então era isso, não esperava esse comportamento da Serial, por isso estava andando em círculos, obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: Sem dúvida que o uso da função printf() e suas variantes é a melhor escolha para se formatar saídas de strings em um programa em C comum, porém no Arduino, esta função irá consumir 1.5k a mais de memória de programa, o que pode vir a ser importante em sua aplicação. Sem contar a complexidade (para um iniciante) envolvida para seu uso com o Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Veja em principio seu problema é no uso da função `print`/`println` do objeto `Serial` estas funções quando lidando com números do tipo `float` e `double` permite informar quantos dígitos serão usados para a parte fracionada do número fornecido. O padrão é dois portanto seu problema se resume a isto, usar um número maior de casas como no exemplo abaixo onde usei 30 casas, o que é bem além da resolução capaz do Arduino, seja qual for a arquitetura usada.

***Mas Atenção, há alguns conhecimentos que talvez já tenha, mas é importante reforçar***.

No Arduino MEGA é usado microcontroladores de 8 bits da família AVR, portanto o tipo numérico que escolheu, `long` ocupa quatro bytes mas não permite frações ou seja ponto flutuante.

Portanto, você precisa fazer um **casting** para um tipo de maior precisão, sendo **Arduino MEGA** ou outro da família de 8 bits, não fará diferença em usar `Float` ou `Double`, você terá a mesma precisão que será de 6 a 7 dígitos, sendo os valores limites 3.4028235E+38 no máximo e no mínimo -3.4028235E+38.

Mas na família do Arduino DUE ou seja microcontroladores ARM que são de 32 bits, você terá uma maior precisão usando o tipo Double já que este irá ocupar 8 bytes (mesmo a documentação dizendo que double e long tem o mesmo tamanho), e estes tem precisão de 15 dígitos.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  long x = 234;
  long y = 343;
  long z = 731;

   Serial.println(x/y);
   Serial.println(x/(float)y,30);
   Serial.println(x/(double)y,30);

   Serial.println(x/z);
   Serial.println(x/(float)z,30);
   Serial.println(x/(double)z,30);

   Serial.println(y/z);
   Serial.println(y/(float)z,30);
   Serial.println(y/(double)z,30);

   Serial.println(z/y);
   Serial.println(z/(float)y,30);
   Serial.println(z/(double)y,30);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

No código acima, se executado no **Arduino Mega** (ou outro da **família AVR** - **8-bits**) terá o seguinte resultado:

```
58
58.500000000000000000000000000000  
58.500000000000000000000000000000

0
0.320109415054321289062500000000
0.320109415054321289062500000000

0
0.005471956253051757812500000000
0.005471956253051757812500000000

182
182.750000000000000000000000000000
182.750000000000000000000000000000
```

E por sua vez, no **Arduino DUE** (e outros da **família ARM** - **32-bits**) dará o seguinte resultado:

```
58
58.500000000000000000000000000000
58.500000000000000000000000000000

0
0.320109426975250244140625000000
0.320109439124487016314901666191

0
0.005471956450492143630981445312
0.005471956224350204678330555907

182
182.750000000000000000000000000000
182.750000000000000000000000000000
```

**ATENÇÃO**

Observe a falha de precisão que ocorre no **Arduino DUE** quando se usa float, e pede ao `Serial.println()` imprimir com 30 casas decimais.

### Tamanhos dos Tipos

#### Long

32 bits (4 bytes), de -2,147,483,648 a 2,147,483,647

#### Double

3.4028235E+38 no máximo e para o mínimo -3.4028235E+38. No Arduino MEGA e família ocupam (4 bytes) de informação.

Já no Arduino DUE e família ocupam (8 bytes) de informação.

#### Float

Idêntico ao Double no Arduino Mega e família, porém cuidado 2.0 é diferente de (4/2.0), devido ao método de codificação numérica adotado ([IEEE 754](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) para números de ponto flutuante de 32 bits).

No Arduino DUE apresenta resultados também inesperados quando usando uma maior precisão.

#### int (Integer)

De -32,768 até 32,767  para o Arduino Mega e família, já que ocupa 2 bytes

No Arduino Due, usa 32-bit (4-byte). sendo portanto de -2,147,483,648 até 2,147,483,647 ou seja idêntico ao `long`

### Mais informações:

1. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Long
2. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double
3. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Float
4. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int
5. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html
6. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754
7. http://carlosdelfino.eti.br/logicadeprogramacao/nivel_4/Representando_Numeros_em_Ponto_Flutuante/